# Driver I/O pipe redirection

Tags: windows, pipe

I am trying to sandbox I/O with multiple composite windows and I need to pipe whole driver I/O of sandboxed application.

I know how to pipe stdout stdin stderr on Windows, but I want to Pipe all output input devices availible. In C/C++.

How do I list them?

Can I store the old device pipe end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to list them by
DeviceIOControl in win32 API
or by
ioctl in unix-like OSes.